# The dependency is missing from repository (error 404)

Tags: java, maven, reflections

I'm trying to use the [reflections-maven](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) plugin in a project.

However, Maven refuses to compile the project because the following dependency is missing:

```
<groupId>org.jfrog.jade.plugins.common</groupId>
<artifactId>jade-plugin-common</artifactId>
<version>1.3.8</version>
```

I checked on the Maven central repository. The dependency is missing there (error 404).

How can I use reflections-maven without this dependency ?

**NOTA:**

- The rules in my company disallow the use of custom repositories directly in `pom.xml`.
- The internal Nexus **MUST** be used.

Comment: download specific jar manually and add that in lib.

Comment: @Orion I don't want to commit any libraries with my project in SVN. The project must compile with maven only.

Comment: Your configuration of the repositories is wrong, cause the artifact is not available via Maven Central. So you need to configure supplemental repositories or start using a repository manager.

Comment: @khmarbaise Please re-read my post, I can't use any repository except the one from my company.

Comment: Then why not ask for reflections-maven to be added to your internal nexus?

Comment: So as already mentoined ask to add the appropriate repository to your internal repository manager.

Comment: @SimonVerhoeven The admins of the internal nexus allow only "official" repositories :\

Comment: You don't have a repository in your repo manager like `3rdParty` to solve such issues? If not request to create one. Otherwise your admins don't understand Maven and neither the intention of a repository manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your requirements\limitations seem to be:

1. not available in global nexus
2. can't be added to your internal nexus
3. don't want to add it to your lib folder

The only remaining option seems to be for you to install it to your local maven repository as described here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html

of course this will present issues on your build server and other teammembers will have to do the same, but I can't think of another solution given the limitations.